# Recursive $.ajax function and allowing browser to refresh/render updated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recursion, settimeout

I have an issue with js promises that I hope someone can help me with. The function myFunction below performs a $.ajax call and therefore returns a promise. As I need to hand control back to the browser in order to show the refreshed div that this function updates as I recurse, I'm calling a setTimeout as follows:

```
var nextBitOfWork = function () {
    return myFunction(email);
};
setTimeout(nextBitOfWork, 0);
```

where myFunction (which recurses) now returns a promise when it's done doing it's $.ajax call.

If I simply call:

```
return myFunction(email);
```

without the setTimeout function construct above, the promise is passed through and all my promises are captured and allow me to get the array output I need and everything works great when recursion ends. But without the setTimeout I don't get the browser refresh. Using it as above I get the div update refresh displaying, but seem to lose the promise and so the script continues and I don't get to fill the array that myFunction builds as it recurses.

Any thoughts on how to make sure the setTimeout passes on the promise reliably so that I build the response array and display the div updates as I do so?

Thanks, in advance, for your help!

OK - now have the following:

```
var func = function () {
    myFunction(email);
};
return refreshscreen(func,0);
```

where refreshscreen is:

```
function refreshscreen(func,time) {
    var timer = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function () {
        return func().then(timer.resolve()); 
    }, time);
    return timer.promise();
}
```

Still the same issue - although the browser renders the div, the array I build with myFunction for the collected $.ajax responses is only 1 element in length - though it recurses 20 times! Without the call to refresh screen, the array builds fine, but the browser never renders the div's as we recurse!

Comment: What about using callbacks instead by (eventually, if needed) queuing the requests?

Comment: Would mean a very major code re-write - know this is possible with promises but not sure how to construct  the settimeout(s) to handle it!

Comment: In your edit, `func` needs to return the promise received from `myFunction`. (You can also remove the `return` within `setTimeout`)

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` does not return the value returned by the function that you pass in. (It returns a value you can use to stop the timeout by passing it in to `clearTimeout`)

So in order to receive the returned value from `myFunction` just wrap it in a function in your call to setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(function () {
  var promise = myFunction(email);
  // do something with promise...
}, 0);
```